# How can I show my data in A listview ? (Asynchrone Okhttp)

Tags: java, android

Can anyone help me with my codes because my app crashes. My data are not show in my list view at all when I press the button. I use class `JSONAsynchrone` and in it I put:

```
@Override
protected String doInBackground(String... strings) {
    OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
    Request request = new Request.Builder().url("http://localhost/gsbfrais/TousVisiteursSwissJson.php").build();
    Response response = null;
    try {
        response = client.newCall(request).execute();
        return response.body().string();

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}


@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String json) {
    pDialog.dismiss();
    //textViewDonnees.setText(json);
    JSONObject c=null;
    try {
        // Getting JSON Array from URL
        JSONArray android = new JSONArray(json);
        for(int i = 0; i < android.length(); i++){
            c = android.getJSONObject(i);
            //VIS_MATRICULE, VIS_NOM, VIS_PRENOM, VIS_ADRESSE, VIS_VILLE, VIS_CP
            String id = c.getString(TAG_matricule);
            String nom = c.getString(TAG_nom);
            String prenom = c.getString(TAG_prenom);
            String adresse = c.getString(TAG_adresse);
            String ville = c.getString(TAG_ville);
            String cp = c.getString(TAG_cp);

            Visiteur vis = new Visiteur(id,nom,prenom,adresse,ville,cp);
            oslist.add(vis);

        }   // fin du for
        //textViewDonnees.setText(oslist.get(i).toString());
        listDesVisiteurs=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.listDesVisiteurs);
        final ArrayAdapter<Visiteur> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<Visiteur>(page_2.this,R.layout.support_simple_spinner_dropdown_item, oslist);
        listDesVisiteurs.setAdapter(adapter);

        listDesVisiteurs.setAdapter(adapter);

        listDesVisiteurs.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,int position, long id) {
                Toast.makeText(page_2.this, "Vous avez cliqué le visiteur "+oslist.get(+position).nomVis, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

        });

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        Log.i("e",e.toString());
        Log.i("DEBUG", "bouton cliqué");
    }
}
```

Comment: What is your crash log say ? If your url is local host then you have to run in emulator . In real device it won't be worked.

Comment: You can debug the response check if the `JSONObject` is right or not, and check `oslist` size is empty or not

Comment: So my url is good ^^ and I don't know how to do @Magic

Comment: what is your IDE. Eclipse or Android Studio? Android Studio you can look at this [link](https://developer.android.com/studio/debug)

Comment: I use Android Studio and no bugs

Comment: I mean you should set the breakpoint in `onPostExecute` method to check the response is right or not and debug step by step check list adapter data source is ok or not. Because your url is a `localhost` url we don't know the response structure and don't know have you parse the JSONObject right or not. You should learn how to find the reason with debug tools